Any reference about neumann eigenvalue problem
I would like to get a good reference for the study of the following eigenvalue problem
$$ -\Delta u + u = 0, \quad \mbox{in} \ \Omega \quad \mbox{and} \quad 
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} = \lambda u, \quad \mbox{on} \ \partial \Omega.
$$
Here $\Omega$ is a smooth bounded domain contained in $\mathbb{R}^N$. More precisely, i would like to find some reference that study the spectral theory of this problem and describe the eigenvalues, if the first eigenvalue is positive, if we can write $H^1(\Omega)$ as the direct sum of the eigenspaces generated by the eigenfunctions, regularity of the eigenfunctions, positivity of the first eigenfunction, this type of results. Any help is very appreciated.

The PDE is a Poisson Equation. This is also a variation of Schrodinger's Equation for a free particle. The neumann condition probably isolates solutions t specific momenta.

Mary Boas' Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences should have everything you need. As well as any textbooks on PDEs.  Boundaries help determine the eigenvalue.

This is a version of the Steklov eigenvalue problem.  Googling this will give you a number of options for in-depth treatments, but here is a brief sketch of what you can do.
Let's take for granted the associated solvability theory for the Neumann problem, namely that for any $F \in (H^1(\Omega))^\ast$ there exists a unique $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ such that $-\Delta u + u = f$ in the weak sense:
$$
B(u,v) := \int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot \nabla v + uv = \langle f, v \rangle \text{ for all } v \in H^1(\Omega).
$$
Now, any $g \in H^{-1/2}(\partial \Omega) = (H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega))^\ast$ gives rise to an element of $(H^1(\Omega))^\ast$ via the map
$$
H^1(\Omega) \ni v \mapsto \langle g,Tv \rangle_{-1/2,1/2} \in \mathbb{R}
$$
since the trace map $T : H^1(\Omega) \to H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$ is bounded.  This means that we have a map $\Lambda : H^{-1/2}(\partial \Omega) \to H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$ defined by $\Lambda g = T u$, where $B(u,v) = \langle g,Tv \rangle_{-1/2,1/2}$ for all $v \in H^1(\Omega)$.
Next we observe that
$$
H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega) \hookrightarrow L^2(\partial \Omega) \hookrightarrow  H^{-1/2}(\partial \Omega)
$$
and that these embeddings are compact due to Rellich's theorem.  Thus, we can define the map $K : L^2(\partial \Omega) \to L^2(\partial \Omega)$ to be the restriction of $\Lambda$ to  $L^2(\partial \Omega)$.  Now one can check that $K$ is bounded, linear, compact and satisfies
$$
\int_{\partial \Omega} Kf g = B(u_f,u_g) = B(u_g,u_f) = \int_{\partial \Omega} f Kg 
$$
where $u_f,u_g \in H^1(\Omega)$ denote the weak solutions associated to $f,g$ respectively.  In particular, $K$ is self-adjoint and
$$
\int_{\partial \Omega} Kf f = B(u_f,u_f) = \Vert u_f \Vert_{H^1}^2 >0 \text{ for } f \neq 0,
$$
so actually $K$ is positive definite too.  We can then use the spectral theorem for compact self-adjoint operators to get an orthonormal basis $\{f_n\} \subset L^2(\partial \Omega)$ of $K$ eigenfunctions with eigenvalues $\{\mu_n\} \subset (0,\infty)$ with $\mu_n \to 0$.  Setting $\lambda_n = 1/\mu_n \to \infty$ and $u_n = u_{f_n}$, one can prove that $f_n = \lambda_n T u_n$ on $\partial \Omega$ and
$$
B(u_n,v) = \int_{\partial \Omega} \lambda_n T u_n Tv \text{ for all }v \in H^1. 
$$
This can be used to show that $\{ \sqrt{\lambda_n} u_n\}$ is an orthonormal set in $H^1(\Omega)$, but it only spans $(H^1_0(\Omega))^\bot$, the orthogonal complement of $H^1_0(\Omega) = T^{-1}(\{0\})$.
From here one can prove that the defining characteristic of $\lambda_0>0$ (the principal eigenvalue) is that
$$
\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2 + u^2 = B(u,u) \ge \lambda_0 \int_{\partial \Omega} |Tu|^2 \text{ for all }u \in H^1(\Omega).
$$
This is sharp, as equality is achieved for $u = u_0$.  In other words, $\mu_0 = 1/\lambda_0$ is the best embedding constant for the trace operator $T$.

Thank you so much. I found a nice paper by searching for "Steklov" problem. Also, the details that you provide help me so much.

@RodolfoFerreiradeOliveira You're quite welcome - glad to be of assistance!
